# Now On Tap is missing from Marshmallow

Tags: nexus-5, google-now, 6.0-marshmallow

I recently flashed the stable version of [Cataclysm](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/orig-development/rom-cataclysm-nexus-5-t2518660) onto my Nexus 5 ([Cataclysm Oct 27, 2015 Stable release](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63502790&postcount=25234)). Cataclysm adds several features including AppOps over a mostly stock system.

However, [Now On Tap](https://www.android.com/versions/marshmallow-6-0/) is missing from my system. Holding down on the home button just brings me to the Google Now cards screen. This happens on the [Google Experience Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.launcher), the 3rd party [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher), and various apps including Facebook, Inbox, Telegram and WhatsApp.

In case I accidentally disabled it during setup, I've looked through the settings to try to re-enable it but haven't been able to find the option.

[image: now-cards][image: voice][image: screen]

As far as I know, Cataclysm doesn't disable Now on Tap or affect it in any way. I previously flashed the stock system image for 6.0 where Now On Tap was present.

Just in case, I checked: the [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) apk version is 5.4.28.19.arm, which was updated on 22 Oct 2015 so that's probably not the issue.

Comment: According to [this post on the Cataclysm XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63267157&postcount=23887), "*System language have to be set to English (UK or US)*"

Comment: Yeah I did make sure it was set to US in the Google App, but apparently System Language is a separate thing. Thanks for the tip. Resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (as of current writing), Google Now on Tap only available if **the System language is set to English**.

From [Official Google Support for Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6304517),

> **What languages is this feature available in?**
>
> Now on tap is currently only available in English.

Perhaps an understatement, since setting the language to English in Google Search app doesn't show the option for Now on Tap.

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/3noa1a/now_on_tap_only_works_with_english_system_language/),

> **Now On Tap only works with English system language.**
>
> Just a heads up.
>
> I tested it, and it checks out - with system language set to English, you'll find a Now On Tap toggle under Settings - Google - Search and Now. In another language, that toggle isn't there.

As for the follow-up, it seems any English language is accepted, not only English (US) or English (UK)

> Any English (UK, AUS, India)? Or just US English?
>   I guess I could try it and find out but *goggle wont gib oats!*
>
> - US and UK worked for me.
> - Working fine on English (India)
> - English AU works fine

Comment: There are other factors that might disable this feature, such as [using Google Apps/Business account](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/3noa1a/now_on_tap_only_works_with_english_system_language/cvq5lc2), will expand/write as another answer if necessary.